# How to invite other gym trainer in Wyndom Stadium?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In several of the post-game guides for Pokemon Sword & Shield, I see that people say that you can rematch the gym trainers in the Wyndom Stadium. They say that you need to invite them, but no one seems to describe *how* to invite them. They are not in their original gyms and they are not in Wyndom stadium.

I feel like it has to be something obvious since no one describes how to do it, but I just can't seem to see it.

Apparently you can also rematch Hop, but again, *how*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to invite each gym leaders (also Leon, Hop, Bede, and Marnie), you need to get their gold cards.

- You need to have finish the post-game adventure, for next trainers :

  **Leon** : Battle him at **Battle Tower**
  **Hop** : Finish the post-game by battling him, deep inside **Slumbering Weald** (You must have begin the post-game part by beginning at this place too, the endgame show that we must return to this place)
  **Marnie** : You need to find her in Budew Drop Inn, then go rebattle her at **Spikemuth** after the post-game adventure, next to the Pokemon Center
- These one are given during the post-game adventure :

  **Piers** : You get it during the post-game
  **Post-game Gym Leaders** : you get their gold cards when you go to their stadium during the post-game

  > Note that Bede is the new **Fairy** Gym Leader
- Unknow location :

  **Opal** : *I don't remember when or where you get it, probably during post-game*

Comment: Marnie is not during the post-game story like Bede, it's a separate thing *after* that whole story is over. First you find her in Budew Drop Inn, then she'll be in Spikemuth.

Comment: @Pyritie I fixed that, thanks :)

Comment: Also, I checked if I had the Opal gold card (which is the case), but don't know when and where I get it :(

Comment: I think you get it during the post-game story at the same time you get bede's, but I'm not sure

Comment: I found Marnie in Budew Drop Inn, then she ran away (without giving me anything) so now I don't where she is, where does she after Budew Drop? She wasn't in Spikemouth. Also where are all the other trainers? When I go to the stadiums the trainers aren't there, so how do I talk to them or get their card?

Comment: @Maxim you need to start the post-game adventure (did you catch Zacian/Zamazenta *which depends of your version sword/shield* ?); if you don't catch them, you need to go deep into **Slumbering Weald** as said in the *Hop* part)

Comment: Ah, OK, I'll do that, I didn't catch Zacian yet, maybe that's the "obvious thing" I was missing

Comment: @Maxim You won't catch Zacian at this position, that's just the start point to begin (and end) the post-game adventure, which is necessary to get each gold cards

Comment: I got it now, I didn't realize that there a entire epilogue to reach the *real* post-game >_<